# Geometry coordinates with distance given

Tags: geometry

How do you find two missing coordinates with the distance given? There is one $y$ missing and one $x$ missing. I have no problem with one but do not know how to find two. The distance is $\sqrt{113}$ with $x_1 = 8$ and $y_2 = 13$. I have to find $x_2$ and $y_1$.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What distance is given?

Answer (score 1):

If you are told that the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $\sqrt{113}$, then we have:

$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2 = 113$

$(x_2-8)^2+(y_1-13)^2 = 113$

There are infinitely many solutions for $x_2,y_1$. However, if you are given that $x_2,y_1$ are integers, then there are only a few solutions (8 to be precise).